# Python HTTP Request in exact time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, clock

im trying to find a way to make my HTTP request in a exact time for my computer example 13:02:00:00.
Any recomendation?

Comment: Which means Real-time Application ?, You actually need to find key-word 
"real-time" - hope it will help

Comment: You could do this in many ways, but you **should** do this with either a cronjob or Task Scheduler so you don't have a long-running Python process, which would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, it depends on your network speed. Anyway, I think that's impossible as when you make a GET request, your request will pass through many network devices such as a router, switch, and finally reaches a server where IP address of the site will be sent to you. Even request that is sent will travel with the speed of light you can't get it in exact time, as some switches will make ARP requests to get to know destination address.

Comment: But i need an aprox time, i know the Request can be sended at 13:00:00 and the server got the request in 13:03:79 for example.